# Downloading preorders from iTunes in iOS6

Tags: itunes, ios

I preordered some music last night via iTunes on my computer at home. I have an iPad at work that is bound to the same iTunes account. I go to the "Purchased" section in iTunes on the iPad and my preorder isn't there. The preorder has been released and i received my confirmation from Apple this morning that it in fact has.

How can I download my preorder?

Comment: Has the preorder been released? Can you tell exactly what you preordered?

Comment: @duci9y - updated.

Comment: Although I have never preordered tracks before here’s my take. Search for the track in the store on your iPad and download it from there.

Comment: im afraid that its going to charge me again.

Comment: What does the button say? Does it say “Buy” or “Download”?

Comment: it shows the price.